# Javascript function as parameter - Browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, cross-browser

I know that **the ability to pass function names as parameters** is handled by almost all modern browsers, but I'm wondering about older browsers compatibility:

1. What was the first version of JavaScript/ECMAScript that supported it? Was it supported since the first days of JavaScript? (That would surprise me)
2. What were the versions of each of the major browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, etc.) that first supported it?

Comment: AFAIK you can use anonymous functions as expressions and pass named functions the same as variables pre-IE6, so this has never been an issue.

Comment: `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` both take a function as an argument so it's been supported as long as their was event handling from javascript which is probably the very first origins of javascript since you couldn't do much with javascript without event handling.

Comment: It's always been supported, which doesn't surprise me the least because it's one of the defining features of JavaScript. You can read the first specification here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, functions have always been objects, and objects have always been passable as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The use of *anonymous functions* as *expressions* and the passing of the names of *declared functions* has been available on all *JavaScript* supporting browsers since before Internet Explorer 6.

The first documentation I could find on it is **[ECMA-262](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/)**, which dates as far back as 1997.

If you're talking about full support, old versions of IE ([**even up to IE8**](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs)), suffered from a variable leak in ***named** function expressions*, where the *name* of the *function expression* becomes defined and set in the parent scope, as if it was actually a declared *function*.

```
// Assuming old JScript engine
typeof foo; // "undefined", expected, it's not been defined yet
bar; // defined as if hoisted function declaration, unexpected

var foo = function bar() {};
foo; // as expected
bar; // identical to foo, not expected

foo === bar; // false, they're actually different function objects in memory
```

Answer (score 0):

> What was the first version of JavaScript/ECMAScript that supported it? Was it supported since the first days of JavaScript? (That would surprise me)

1

It is a core language feature.

> What were the versions of each of the major browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, etc.) that first supported it?

The earliest JS supporting browsers support it.